# SQL DB only accessable by single User even though Multi User is active

Tags: c#, sql, database, multi-user

I use a SQL Database in a C# Project and i wanted to make it accessable by multiple Users. I already checked out and it is definitly in Multi User mode but still i get an error that shows me that i can´t connect with several Users on the same Database. Does anyone know what I can do to fix it? Could be something wrong with the code?

Database access with Linq:

```
var queryline = from anmeldung in context.Accounts
                            where anmeldung.Benutzername == BN
                            where anmeldung.Passwort == PW
                            select anmeldung.Id;
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DBtest.Properties.Settings.TestConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=10"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException   HResult=0x80131904   Nachricht =
>   Network-related or instance-specific error when connecting to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or can not be accessed. Verify that
>   the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote
>   connections.. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Verbindung
>   mit SQL Server konnte nicht geöffnet werden)   Quelle = .Net SqlClient
>   Data Provider   Stapelüberwachung:    bei
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)    bei
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    bei
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    bei
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    bei
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser
>   user)    bei System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
>   bei System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
>   bei
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)    bei
>   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   bei DBtest.Program.Register(Int32& ID) in
>   \192.168.2.1\Share\DBtest\DBtest\Program.cs: Zeile61    bei
>   DBtest.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   \192.168.2.1\Share\DBtest\DBtest\Program.cs: Zeile102
>
> Innere Ausnahme 1: Win32Exception: Das Zeitlimit für die Semaphore
>   wurde erreicht

Comment: There is no way for us to answer this based on the information you have provided. At the very least, include the results of `select user_access, user_access_desc, * from sys.databases` and the relevant portion of your code.

Comment: added something but i dont know if it helps, i have just started to program

Comment: Translate the error message into english please

Comment: @DanWilson I did google translate the error message, point to not being the database, but twrong server or instance name.